# moving data from html to sql using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

How can I move my data from an html form to ms sql server using asp.net?

Then, how can I call my entire table and list it as an HTML table?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making then displaying in a table a new SQL row using ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083112/making-then-displaying-in-a-table-a-new-sql-row-using-asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this for adding data: http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_add.asp

And check out this for updating data: http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_update.asp